# How can I define shortcut for new blog post in Windows with Word 2013

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

When I want to have a new blog post I need click on

Word shortcut

```
File >> New
```

[image: file new word template shortcut]

From templates click on blog post

[image: new blog post]

How can I define shortcut for this? or another templates that we can import there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use local templates with Office 2013](http://www.poremsky.com/office/use-office-2013-local-templates/)

see Use Pinned Templates

First Go to this address :

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates
```

or

```
%appdata%\microsoft\templates
```

then create a shortcut on desktop

then right click select properties on it and define a hot-key for that...

[image]

every time you have a new idea to writing press that Hotkey and start blogging or writing

Comment: Can you add the relevant details here?